# How to stop mongodb server on Windows startup?

Tags: windows, mongodb, startup

I have mongodb installed on windows 10 and it is always working in the background on windows startup and it is just annoying me cause I don't need to work with it all the time so how do I stop it from running on startup or is the only way to actually remove mongodb?

I tried `mongo admin --eval "db.shutdownServer()"`  but that would only close it but after restart mongodb will show up again in the background :(

Comment: Does it run as a service ? If yes, just configure it to manual.

Comment: thank you.. its much better.. I could always start it from services now when I want to use mongodb :)

Answer (score 51):

Go to your windows `services.msc` and set your mongoDB on manual.
To start your DB open admin prompt `net start mongodb`.
To stop it `net stop mongodb`.